# How can I generate an entire world where every block is a lucky block in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

Does anyone know how to generate a world like this one:

Every single block is a lucky block.

Comment: It's probably just a mod or a downloadable map that makes this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the methods of Vanilla or the Lucky blocks mod. Either you need another mod for that or you can run around and replace stone, dirt etc. with lucky blocks using `/fill`.